# How To Choose A Part Of A Group By Some Criteria MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping

I have the following task:
We have the following MS SQL tables:
Countries - has ID and CountryName,
MountainsCountries - creates a many to many relationship between countries and mountains
Mountains - has ID and MountainName
Peaks - has Id, PeakName and Mountain ID. So we Have Mountain - Peak as one to many relationship.

We need to find highest peak(s) for each country and display them along with their name. We also need to display null whenever a country has no mountains or a mountain has no peaks. We must display both peaks in case there are two highest peaks with the same elevation. The result must look like

Country        Highest Peak Name      Highest Peak Elevation         Mountain
Afghanistan       NULL                  NULL                           NULL
Argentina       Aconcagua               6962                           Andes
Bulgaria         Musala                 2925                           Rila

I can do the task if we do not need to display peaks' names. But I can't figure it out now. When I make a GROUP BY Country and mountain, how to select just the highest peak(s)? I was thinking about ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY...) but it will return just the first highest peak. So if we have two peaks the same height we will not take both as we have to. Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT c.CountryName, p.PeakName, MAX(p.Elevation) AS [HighestPeakElevation], m.MountainRange AS [Mountain]
FROM Countries c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN MountainsCountries mc ON c.CountryCode = mc.CountryCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN Mountains m ON m.Id = mc.MountainId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Peaks p ON p.MountainId = m.Id
GROUP BY CountryName, MountainRange
??????????
HAVING p.Elevation = MAX(p.Elevation) ???
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you just want `ROW_NUMBER()` with ties, try using [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) or `RANK()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.CountryName, p.PeakName, p.Elevation AS [HighestPeakElevation], m.MountainRange AS [Mountain]
FROM Countries c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN MountainsCountries mc ON c.CountryCode = mc.CountryCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN Mountains m ON m.Id = mc.MountainId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Peaks p ON p.MountainId = m.Id 
HAVING p.Elevation = MAX(p.Elevation) OVER (PARTITION BY c.CountryName, m.MountainRange)
```

Or

```
SELECT CountryName, PeakName, HighestPeakElevation, Mountain FROM (SELECT c.CountryName AS CountryName, p.PeakName AS PeakName, p.Elevation AS PeakElevation, MAX (p.Elevation) OVER (PARTITION BY c.CountryName, m.MountainRange) AS [HighestPeakElevation], m.MountainRange AS [Mountain]
FROM Countries c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN MountainsCountries mc ON c.CountryCode = mc.CountryCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN Mountains m ON m.Id = mc.MountainId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Peaks p ON p.MountainId = m.Id) AS t WHERE PeakElevation = HighestPeakElevation
```